# rubymine - can't execute bundle install correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rubymine

I am new to `ruby on rails` and `rubymine`, in rubymine I created a rails project, when try to run it, it seems can't execute `bundle install` automatically, I have to execute `bundle install` in shell by hand first, then could run the project from rubymine successfully.

**My question is:**

Which part did I miss, how to config the linux environment or config rubymine to let it execute `bundle install` automatically & correctly?

Comment: Are you using RVM? If you are check the rubymine project settings so that it using the correct ruby and gemset. You can also setup a `.versions.conf` file so that rvm and Rubymine automatically select the correct ruby/gemset. https://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Comment: I believe it is the same with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). If you are not using one of them you probably should.

Comment: @max I am using RVM, I will try that, thx.

Comment: @max The issue seems fixed by itself now, I don't know the reason, maybe it's some kind of cache or network issue.